# Why did the effects of the Pleistocene extinction not significantly impact African megafauna at the end of the Ice Age?"

Tags: zoology

It seems that megafauna extinctions did not have a significant impact on African megafauna at the end of the Ice Age. Humans also lived in Africa relatively commonly during the end of the Ice Age, just as they did on other continents.

Comment: we are currently at the end of the last ice age,can you please post some links to the research you have done so far as it will help you get better answers.

Comment: Most of the large mammals went extinct in North and South America, Europe, and most parts of Asia more than 10,000 years ago, but the number of large animal species extinct  was relatively low in continental Africa
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S001282521300175X
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268077616_Late_Pleistocene_of_Africa